# In rust, how to apply a function to a variable only if their types are compatible?

Tags: generics, rust, types

In rust, is it possible to write a function that takes a closure and an element of any type, and applies the closure to the element if their types are compatible ?

```rust
fn apply_if_compatible<T, U>(fun: impl Fn(T), element: U) {
    // Executes fun(element) only if T==U
}
```

The end goal is to implement a visitor that is able to visit any struct that implements the [`Serialize`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serialize.html) trait from serde. Since the [`Serializer`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serializer.html) trait must be able to visit any type `T` that implements `Serialize` (without restrictions on the lifetime of the type), I cannot use the `Any` trait. The serializer contains an `FnMut` callback, and needs to be able to call the callback every time it encounters a type that is compatible.

Comment: Doing that requires specialization. It can be emulated (if I'll have time I'll write an answer later) but I won't recommend. I think this is a XY problem.

Comment: Please clarify how this function is used in practice. Why would it be called against an arbitrary `U`? Or would constraining `U` at compile time to always the same as the function's input parameter be OK?

Comment: First, as others have said, I'm pretty sure this is not actually something you want to do - an XY problem, in brief. With that said, can you put any bounds at all on `F` and `T`? I found the (very) unsafe `transmute` function, but even that requires prior knowledge the types are of the same size.

Comment: Such a function would be useful to implement a visitor over a type that is not controlled by the user. The goal is to be able to visit any structure that implements serde::Serialize.

Comment: Does that mean you could reasonably known the type of `fun` in advance? I think this becomes much easier if it can be "Execute a function on `element` iff `element` implements some trait" - in that case it should be a pretty out of the box example of specialization (I think)

Comment: The main question is easy to solve with specialization, but there is no specialization in stable rust. Neither the type of fun nor the type of element are known in advance: we need to be able to visit anything, and do anything with it.

Comment: My mistake; even specialization is unable to handle it soundly.

Comment: I'd be curious to see more of the surrounding code? It doesn't sound like we'll get a closed-form solution here, but I'd like to see what could be done if we pulled back the lens a bit

Comment: I added more context to the question. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If the types are `'static`, you can compare their [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html)s and use a bit of unsafe to work around the type checker:

```rust
fn apply_if_compatible<T: 'static, U: 'static>(fun: impl Fn(T), element: U) {
    if std::any::TypeId::of::<T>() == std::any::TypeId::of::<U>() {
        let element = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(element);
        // SAFETY: We just verified the types are the same.
        let element = unsafe { std::mem::transmute_copy::<U, T>(&element) };
        fun(element);
    }
}
```

You can also go without `unsafe`, if you can afford an allocation or you trust the optimizer to optimize it out (a quick test shows it optimizes away in case the types are not equal, but not when they're equal):

```rust
fn apply_if_compatible<T: 'static, U: 'static>(fun: impl Fn(T), element: U) {
    if let Ok(element) = <Box<dyn std::any::Any>>::downcast(Box::new(element)) {
        fun(*element);
    }
}
```

If the types are not `'static`, I'm afraid there is no solution.

Comment: If U is static, you can even downcast a reference to the element safely, can't you ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast

Comment: @lovasoa Yes, but this needs a `Box`. It may be optimized away, or may not. Anyway, edited, thanks.

Comment: I tried something like this but it complained about the sizes not being the same = is it the use of `transmute_copy` rather than `transmute` that gets around that?

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes. With `transmute()` the compiler cannot prove the sizes are the same and thus issues an error, the regular workaround is to use `transmute_copy()`. But you have to take care to avoid double-drop.

Comment: I cannot know in advance whether the types are going to be 'static. And ideally the solution would not have any runtime overhead, checking whether T==U should be doable at the level of the type system.

Comment: @lovasoa This will certainly constant-fold and compile to noop.